# putStrLn seeing too many arguments haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I have a putStrLn that is seeing a function on a following line and therefore not being compiled properly.

```
if director == "" then
        putStrLn "Please enter a directors name"
        startFunctional 5 userName database --This line is seen as an argument for the putStrLn
    else do
        *etc*
```

I have tried to use brackets to isolate the string, but this throws the same error.

Error message:

```
The function `putStrLn' is applied to five arguments, but its type `String -> IO ()' has only one
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible that you're missing a `do` block?

```
if director == "" 
then do
    putStrLn "Please enter a directors name"
    startFunctional 5 userName database
else do
    *etc*
```

Also, try to align the `then` and `else` keywords of an `if` block.

Comment: Aligning `then` and `else` might be good style, but is certainly no requirement. Apart from the special case of `if-then-else` appearing *within* a `do` block, none of the keywords `if`, `then` or `else` trigger any kind of layout behaviour.

Comment: For some reason I thought it did. Thanks!